# how to correctly use curl command line with Services module?

Tags: 7, users, services

I try to use following command to create an user:

```
$ curl -H 'Content-type: application/json'  -d '{"name":"u10", "pass": "123","mail": "user@a.om"}' http://localhost/test/api/user/register
```

return success:

```
{"uid":"11","uri":"http://drupal/daxuebao/api/user/11"}
```

But I try to login:

```
$ curl -H 'Content-type: application/json'  -d '{"username":"u10", "password": "123","mail": "user@a.om"}' http://localhost/test/api/user/login
```

It alert me :

```
["Wrong username or password."]
```

So, How to correctly use curl command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send only username and password. Mail is not required.. Please check the documentation [here](https://drupal.org/node/910598)...

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/test_endpoint';
$data = array(
  'username' => 'admin',
  'password' => 'password',
);
$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$headers = array();
$options = array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data
);
$response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/user/login', $options);
$data = json_decode($response->data);
// Check if login was successful
if ($response->code == 200) {
  // Now recycle the login cookie we recieved in the first request
  $options['headers']['Cookie'] = $data->session_name . '=' . $data->sessid;
  // Get info about a user
  $data = array();
  $options['data'] = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
  $options['method'] = 'GET';
  $response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/user/32', $options);
}
```

Below one worked for me

```
curl -H 'Content-type: application/json'  -d '{"username":"admin", "password": "admin"}' http://localhost/d7/testendpoint/user/login
```

In your case it should be

```
curl -H 'Content-type: application/json'  -d '{"username":"u10", "password": "123"}' http://localhost/test/api/user/login
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It solved! But I still have a question: Why the **password** and **username** attribute different in Login and Register? example: Login: ```{"username":"admin", "password": "admin"}```, but Register ```{"name":"admin", "pass": "admin"}``` ?

Comment: If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235. That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. Regarding, "why different attributes", that is how module was designed..You might need to create a support ticket in project page if you feel it's not correct..